# How-to compare two (or more) INI files?

Tags: windows, comparison

I have two [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) files, and I want see the differences between then (which keys have different values, and which keys one has that the other don't), so...

How-to compare two (or more) [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) files?

Comment: Related: [3-way merge tool](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/32594/3474)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an answer from serverfault.

https://serverfault.com/questions/28194/is-there-a-tool-to-compare-values-in-ini-files

Answer (score 5):

[Try IniCompare](http://www.brothersoft.com/inicompare-222763.html)

[image]

Or have a look at this list of [Ini editors/compare tools](http://compare.software.informer.com/download-compare-ini-file/), though a differencing tool would be the easiest probably

Comment: IniCompare on Vista/Win7 needs a VB DLL. Go here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172991/EN-US/
Download MSVBVM50.CAB. Extract the DLL to the folder where IniCompare.exe is.

Comment: FYI, that KB article just says to download it from http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb5/MSVBVM50.cab, so save yourself a step :-)

Comment: Direct download on editor's page : http://www.kokpeter.dds.nl/Download/index.htm#IniCompare or more directly file http://www.kokpeter.dds.nl/Download/IniCompare_1_0_0.zip

Answer (score 3):

You may use a comparison tool for that, like [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/), an open source and free differencing tool for Windows. It shows the two files side-by-side, colormarking the differences.

Supports Microsoft Windows 98/2000/XP/2003/Vista/7.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Beyond Compare by Scootersoftware for over 10 years now. http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use file compare command-line utility (in any windows)
from the command prompt (enter cmd intor start/run dialog)

```
fc inifile1.ini inifile2.ini
```

The result will be typed aftewards. If you would like to review 
the results

```
fc inifile1.ini inifile2.ini > results.txt
```

After the latter you will see the report in the file results.txt

Comment: +1 for coming with a solution which doesn't require additional software.

Comment: -1 for comming with a solution which doesn't meet the requirements

Answer (score 1):

I found a lovelly windows freeware utility called [ExamDiff](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp) the other day that will do exactly what you want, is user friendly and free. It will even do directory comparisons if you pay for the 'pro' version.

Comment: Only the paid version has plugins, which you need for ini sorting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this service http://inicompare.io/

Compares more than two.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Answer (score 1):

For the reason I didnt found what I was looking for, here my quick and dirty python solution, maybe it helps someone:

```
import configparser as cp

f1 = "org.ini"
f2 = "new.ini"

config1 = cp.ConfigParser()
config2 = cp.ConfigParser()
config1.read(f1)
config2.read(f2)

for section in config1.sections():
    if section not in config2.sections():
        print(section, "NOT in 2")
    else:
        for key in config1[section]:
            if key not in config2[section]:
                print("[miss] section", section, "key", key, "not in new")
            else:
                if config1[section].get(key).split(";")[0].strip() != config2[section].get(key).split(";")[0].strip():
                    print("[chang] section", section, "key", key, config1[section].get(key).split(";")[0].strip(),
                          "org != new", config2[section].get(key).split(";")[0].strip())
for section in config2.sections():
    if section not in config1.sections():
        print(section, "NOT in 1")
    else:
        for key in config2[section]:
            if key not in config1[section]:
                print("[miss] section", section, "key", key, "not in org")
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare 3 files, you can use a [VimDiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)), e.g.

```
vimdiff file1.ini file2.ini file3.ini
```

For GUI tools, check:

- [3-way merge tool for development on Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/32594/3474)
- [Ancestor-based three-way diff/merge with editable output](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2315/3474)
- [Is there a tool to compare values in .ini files?](https://serverfault.com/q/28194/130437)

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a CLI app to deal with this problem when I was dealing with it in the workplace, and my employer was kind enough to let me open source it:

https://github.com/Comcast/compare-ini-files

This will compare 2 or more ini files, and report back on values that are different, and stanzas that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a newer version of this http://winmerge.org/source-code/ which someone has posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/28741/947770) in this thread.

## WinMerge v2

https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge-v2/releases